# AngularJS $resource returns empty object and doesn't update with data

Tags: angularjs, express, single-page-application, angular-resource, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a basic get/post api right now with AngularJS and Express/Node. I'm trying to make a SPA with angular where I can add, get, and delete boards (basically like post-it notes for the web). Every time a button is clicked, it fires $scope.addBoard, which is a $resource object that makes a POST request.

It fires alright, but it returns an empty object that updates the HTML automatically with empty data only. If I want the board populated with information, I have to do a manual refresh of the whole page. I tried incorporating a call back and using a promise, but I can't get either option to work. Is there a way I can get the HTML to update automatically with the full data after the POST request is made the angular way??

services.js

```
  krelloApp.factory('Boards', ['$resource', function($resource) {

  return $resource('api/boards/:id', {}, {
    get: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
    add: {method: 'POST', transformResponse: []}
  });

}]);
```

controller.js

```
krelloApp.controller('boardController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$location', '$http', 'Boards',
function($scope, $resource, $location, $http, Boards) {

  // Get all boards
  $scope.boards = Boards.get();

  // Add board
  $scope.addBoard = function() {
    // Boards.add().then(function(response) {
    //   $scope.boards.push(response);
    // })
    // Boards.add(function(response) {
    //   $scope.boards.push(response)
    // });
    $scope.boards.push(Boards.add());
  };

}]);
```

API Route for POST:

```
  app.post('/api/boards', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    // Add new board to user
    // May need more posts to add lists and stuff
    User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      };
      newBoard = user.generateBoard('Extra Board');
      newList = user.generateList('Extra List');
      newCard = user.generateCard('Extra Card', 'Card Description');
      newList.cards.push(newCard);
      newBoard.lists.push(newList);
      user.boards.push(newBoard);

      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        };
      });

      console.log('Success POST');
      console.log('Added Board to user: ' + req.user.local.email);
      res.json(req.user.boards)
    });
  });
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addBoard()">
      <span class="fa fa-plus-square"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" ng-repeat="board in boards">
    <h1 class="jumbotron">{{ board.title }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got a picture below too. Each board automatically generates a 'title' of 'extra board' that should show when it's generated. Only problem is that the title/data only shows after I manually refresh the whole page. When I click the green button to addBoard, it only gives me an empty board.

[image]
Picture 2: Really odd because it actually shows that the response contains the data, but Angular isn't populating it for some reason.

[image: Firebug Network]

Final Edit (Answer):

Thanks for the help guys. For anybody with the same problem, this is what I changed to fix it:

In services.js, remove transformResponse so it looks like add:{method: 'POST'}.

In the API POST route, change the bottom line where it says res.json(req.user.boards) to res.json(newBoard);

Comment: you probably should be using the first commented out form, but in the `.then`, use `response.data` rather than just `response`.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but the promise isn't registering I think. Gives me error saying it's not a function.

Error: Boards.add(...).then is not a function
$scope.addBoard@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/scripts/controller.js:9:5

Tried:

$scope.addBoard = function() {
    Boards.add().then(function(response) {
      $scope.boards.push(response.data);
      console.log("response: " + response)
      console.log("response.data: " + response.data)
    })
  };

Comment: I just noticed you have `transformResponse : []` on your post.  That is going to disable the default behavior of parsing the response into a JSON object, which is what you are trying to consume.  What happens if you remove this parameter?

Comment: when I take it out, it still populates a board (empty), but it gives me a long error with a link. Description of the error: This error occurs when the $resource service expects a response that can be deserialized as an array but receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays.

Comment: What happens if you push the initial `$resource` object to an array? `$scope.boards=[]; $scope.boards.push(Boards.get());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use the second commented out method with the callback. If you use it like this what do you get?

```
Boards.add({}, function(response) {
  $scope.boards.push(response)
}, function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't give me any errors, though it still is giving me empty boards that only populate with data if I refresh manually.

Comment: Do you control the server as well? If so can you have it return an array? Another thing to try is adding `isArray: false`.. I'm not sure if it works with a POST action though.

Comment: Hallelujah, thanks for the help.  I changed the bottom line of my POST API to res.json(newBoard), my $resource add method to: add: {method: 'POST'}, and stuck with the same idea for the controller: $scope.boards.push(Boards.add());